# Getting error 404 not found in postman while passing url through postman

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

When i pass this url http://localhost:8080/app/users using post request I am getting error 404 not found in postman....

I tried using some changes in my code but giving same error

Here is my controller class:

```java
package com.controller;

import com.entity.User;

import com.repository.UserRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController

@RequestMapping("/app")

public class UserController 

{
    @Autowired

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping("/users")
    public User create(@RequestBody User user)
    {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @GetMapping("/users1")
    public List<User> findAll()
    {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/users/{user_id}")
    public List<User> delete(@PathVariable("user_id") Long userId)
    {
        userRepository.deleteById(userId);
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/{user_id}")
    public Optional<User> findByUserId(@PathVariable("user_id") Long userId)
    {
        return userRepository.findById(userId);
    }
}
```

```
[Directory structure:][1]
```

When i pass url through postman the data should get inserted in the database but it gives me error 404 not found

Comment: Is it a SpringBoot application?

Comment: Yes it is a spring boot application.

Comment: Are you properly scanning packages for Spring stereotypes?

Comment: What IDE do you use? If IDEA, after starting your application switch to `Endpoints` tab, next select `Mappings` sub-tab. Here you can view all REST urls for controllers. Check required one for POST method.

Comment: @Emanuel Ramirez : Yes i  included all dependencies in pom.xml

Comment: @Bor Laze : I am using Eclipse java oxygen.

Comment: Do you see something like `Mapped "{[/users],methods=[POST]}"` in your logs?

Comment: No i don't see logs which you mentioned.

Comment: Here are my some logs in console : 2019-07-18 23:23:28.748  INFO 8956 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-07-18 23:23:28.748  INFO 8956 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-07-18 23:23:28.768  INFO 8956 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 20 ms

Comment: other APIs are working ?

Comment: No.The other apis also not working.

Comment: Hello @RadhikaParkhe, make sure your app is running on 8080 and make the request, if that doesn't help can you share your git link of the project to identify the issue

Comment: @RadhikaParkhe Could you please share more details like directory structure etc. From your package structure it's possible that you have placed your main application class within another package and the controller package is not getting scanned properly.

Comment: @Patel Romil : My app is running on 8080. This is my git link of the project : https://github.com/RadhikaParkhe212/persondetails1.git

Comment: @Ananthapadmanabhan :I posted screenshot in the question but it's not visible. No, i placed main class in main class package.

Comment: Error solved. I didn't have the packages in the sequence as required. Main class should be in com.crud.Persondetails & other packages should be like com.crud.Persondetails.tr that's i did now in my project.Thank you all for your help & time.